# XMLHttpRequest status returning 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have some bit of code from the internet that updates my webpage when I type in a `text input`.

My code is below

```
function validate(field, query) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a href='index.php'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

After debugging I found out that the code is run twice (afaik). The first time `xmlhttp.readyState` is 1, meaning that the request is being set up. The second time it's 4 meaning it's complete. So this is working like intended.

The problem is that it always returns the `Error Occurred` bit in the field. The reason why is that `xmlhttp.status` keeps the status number 404, meaning that it is not found. I have no clue why it returns 404. If the browser I'm using is important, I'm using the latest version of Safari. I also checked the latest version of Chrome and got the same problem.

Comment: see this link:http://forums.iis.net/t/1159510.aspx?ServerXMLHTTP+Returns+HTML+Error+404+But+URL+is+Valid

Comment: Use the Network tab of Chrome's dev tools to see if your code is requesting the correct URL.

Comment: @Seventoes, please post this as an answer if you want some rep and I can complete this question. I used the dev tools and found out that `xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);` starts in the default directory and the file was in `/scripts/validation.php`. Adding `/scripts/` in front of `validation.php` fixed it.

Comment: Done! Chrome's dev tools are absolutely invaluable when doing any sort of web dev. It should be sitting there open at all times while developing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your code is actually requesting the correct URL. You can do this with most modern browser's developer tools, including the Network tab of Chrome's.